# Why do intersection of two quadratic forms implies elliptic curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field and $S=k[T_0,T_1,T_2,T_3]$ and $f,g\in S_2$ two relatively prime quadratic forms. How can I show that the intersection $X\subset \mathbb P_k^3$ of second degree surfaces $V_+(f)$ and $V_+(g)$  has genus 1?

Does this follows from syzygy theorem or what should I use here?

Comment: Use the adjunction formula to show that $X$ has trivial canonical bundle. By the way, the phrase "pairwise irreducible" does not make sense.

Comment: Hmm. I think I translated the problem correctly and there was used the term "pairwise irreducible". It looks like I don't understand that part correctly.

Comment: I'm stydying algebraic geometry on my own by doing old exercises found on the Internet. I found a course from the university of Helsinki's www-site, http://www.math.helsinki.fi/kurssit/alggeom/h15.gif problem 6. So I translated the problem from Finnish.

Comment: Maybe @JyrkiLahtonen can weigh in on the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, one way is indeed to use syzygies.

Denote the curve by $C$. Then there is a resolution of the form 
$$
0 \to \mathscr O_{\mathbb P^3}(-4) \to \mathscr O_{\mathbb P^3}(-2)^{\oplus 2} \xrightarrow{\alpha} \mathscr O_{\mathbb P^3} \to \mathscr O_C \to 0.
$$

This is not a short exact sequence, so we have to break it into two short exact sequences:

$$
0 \to \ker \alpha \to \mathscr O_{\mathbb P^3} \to \mathscr O_C \to 0.
$$

and

$$
0 \to \mathscr O_{\mathbb P^3}(-4) \to \mathscr O_{\mathbb P^3}(-2)^{\oplus 2}  \to \ker \alpha \to 0.
$$

We are interested in $H^1(\mathscr O_C)$. By the long exact sequence of cohomology, we have 
$$
0 \to H^1(\mathscr O_C) \to H^2(\ker \alpha) \to 0
$$
since $H^1(\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^3})=H^2(\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^3})=0$. Then from the second exact sequence we get:
$$
0 \to H^2(\ker \alpha) \to H^3(\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^3}(-4)) \to H^3(\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^3}(-2))^{\oplus 2}=0
$$
Hence $h^2(\ker \alpha)=h^3(\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^3}(-4))=h^0(\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^4})=1$.

Comment: Is there an explanation of steps here to someone unfamiliar with algebraic geometry although familiar with algebra?

Comment: @turbo How much algebraic geometry do you know/what do you not understand? This is basically an abstract nonsense proof by general properties of cohomology.

Comment: Thank you for responding my comment. Is there a path through classical stuff without cohomology operations? (1) It would help me understand. (2) It would help me relate cohomology with classical stuff so I could study.

Comment: @Turbo I'm not sure I fully understand your first question, but have you looked at Harris' book? ("Algebraic Geometry: A First Course") The choice of topics is very classical and the treatment is very elementary.

Comment: All these $\mathcal{O}$ require some higher thought to understand. Is there a path from study of equations like from elementary elimination theory study?